# What is the alternative for number(2,0) of oracle in sqlserver?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

in  my oracle tables some columns are having `number(2,0)`, `number(5,0)` datatype, so I want to know what are the alternative datatypes in sql server for that .

Comment: [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187746.aspx) AKA `numeric`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The T-SQL equivalent is [`DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-AR/library/ms187746.aspx).

Examples: `NUMERIC(2, 0)` and `DECIMAL(5, 0)`

They are *functionally equivalent*.

Here's a breakdown of the  **exact** numeric types:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Following are some alternatives in sql server

```
numeric(2,0)
decimal(2,0)
```

and as it haven't floating point you can take

```
int
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187746.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [Numeric data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

```
NUMERIC(2, 0)
```

The first parameter specifies the maximum total number of decimal digits that can be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point.

The second parameter specifies the maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Numeric Datatypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848794.aspx)

Depending on your data you could use:

- [decimal and numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)
- [float and real](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx)
- [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)
- [money and smallmoney](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx)

IIRC, Oracle stores pretty much all manner of numbers and floats in the `number` datatype whereas SQL Server splits them out in to individual datatypes